# How to get firefox to re-post data on page refresh?

Tags: html, firefox, xhtml, browser

I'm currently developing an application that needs to behave consistently across all browsers.  One of my pages loads in response to form submission. When the user refreshes the window at this page, all browsers except Firefox re-submit the data and loads the page correctly.

How can I get firefox to also re-post the form data on page reload?

Comment: When I hit `CMD+R` in Firefox I'm asked whether the form should be send again, like in the other browsers. How do you submit the form? And a little note: If the user clicks in the address bar and hits enter, the page is always reloaded without submitting the form. Maybe you could store the values in a session and check whether the form was send and store new values or retrieve the data from the last call.